# "External component has thrown an exception"

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a windows service in C#. After running 1-2 days(not specific), the service stops ( it actually does not stop, but it is not processing anything. Service status is still "Started", I need to manually restart the service, then it works again).

The exception logged is "**External component has thrown an exception**". This occurs in a third party control.

I wanted the service to continue without any halt, as in production no one is going to check the service whether it is up/processing or not unless the particular functionality stops.

I have all TRY..CATCH in place.

Any suggestion, how can I ensure that Service continues even though above error occurs?

Comment: First of all, log the entire exception. Log `ex.ToString()`, and not just `ex.Message`. There was almost certainly an inner exception, telling you what exactly happened, and where.

Answer (score 0):

Use this try-catch construct instead.

```
try{
}catch{
}
```

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Language-Basics/Usethecatchallcatchstatement.htm

Comment: thanks for reply.. but i have already mentioned in post that try..catch are already in place... any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to do something like this in your catch block:

```
public static void RestartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
  ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
  try
  {
    int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

    service.Stop();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

    // count the rest of the timeout
    int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
    timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec2-millisec1));

    service.Start();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
  }
  catch
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

If the RestartService fails, you can stop your Service all together.  Code samples [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/)